# Xamarin iOS Webview auto execute OnClientClick()

Tags: vb.net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

First, I sorry for my bad English to explain to everybody. :((

I have a problem. My Xamarin iOS using WebView in loading my Website created in VB.Net

I have 1 delete button and when i click on it, it shows confirm dialog for the user confirmation before deleting, but when I click Ok it is not working and when I go back to the previous page and come back to same page again and click Delete button confirmation Dialog is displayed but task is auto-executed even when I have not chosen anything.

My aspx code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete');" ommandName="Delete" CommandArgument=""  />
```

My aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    // Do the logic delete on DB

    Master.Redirect("previousPage.aspx")
End Sub
```

How I can fix it.

Comment: Not addressing your question, but Apple will reject all apps referencing UIWebView, and you should  [migrate to WKWebView](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/) instead.

Comment: Tks @VahidShir I didn't customize render so and I just update grade to Xamarin Form 4.5+ for resole this.

Comment: Yes, start from Xamarin.forms 4.5+, Xamarin replaced UIWebView with WKWebView, here is the [document link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-itms-90809).

Comment: Tks @JackHua-MSFT but it not a root cause. I had resolved it by using Jquery Confirm Library instead javascript confirms dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue.

I don't know why this issue going, it's will have a problem with all confirm dialog.

I using a Jquery Confirm Library https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/ replace all confirm dialog with javascript and it works perfect.